# Can Anaconda3 and Python-IDLE coexist on the same computer?

Tags: anaconda, python-idle, anaconda3

I just installed **Anaconda3 (64-bit) Individual Edition** on my Windows 7 machine. I was instructed to do this by setup instructions for an upcoming workshop I'm attending; they said, "Installing all of Python's research packages individually can be a bit difficult, so we recommend Anaconda, an all-in-one installer."

*Is it possible to install another Python IDE, such as IDLE, on the same computer as Anaconda?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely yes.
My pc is also running at 64 bits and windows 7.
I have Anaconda (Spyder as editor) and IDLE (interactive shell) at the same time.
Having Anaconda is useful in sense that lots of packages of modules were included when we install it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your question right, but I have Anaconda on my computer + PyCharm, I didn't face trouble

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, but i think Anaconda is going to override the packages installed from python installer.